# How to select a specific number of bytes from SQLite table?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a simple SQLite table with 1 column where I'm selecting a random number of records:

```
SELECT * FROM vocabulary ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 100;
```

Is there a way to select a specific number of bytes, instead of rows? Something along the lines of:

```
SELECT * FROM vocabulary ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT BYTES 1024;
```

Comment: No, this is not possible.

Comment: Do you mean bytes across rows or bytes from a individual blob?

Comment: @SamuelNeff Bytes across rows.

Comment: @ArmanH, ok, can't do that, sorry.  Not hard to do it in your calling code though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't limit your select via the SQLite-engine to a specific number of bytes across rows.  Note though that `LIMIT` simply stops reading when the limit is reached.  You can do the same thing by keeping a count in your calling code and then stop reading the data once you've reached the number of bytes you want.

Precisely how will depend on what environment you're programming in.